# org-edit-special to respect the :lines parameter of `+INCLUDE`s

Tags: org-mode

When one invoke `org-edit-special` at the line containing an `#+INCLUDE`, it opens a new buffer with the referenced file. Although, if an `#+INCLUDE` contains the `:lines` clause it will not respect what is written in it.

Is there a method to enforce opening file at the place referenced by the `:lines` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code for `org-edit-special`, you'll see that all it's doing when called on a line containing `#+INCLUDE`, is calling `org-open-link-from-string` with the filename as a string.

In that sense the answer is no, there is currently no Org built-in setting you can change to have `org-edit-special` respect the `:lines` clause.

You could hack `org-open-link-from-string` such that it takes an additional optional argument `linenum`, and hack org-edit-special to read the line number from your `:lines` clause and pass it to `org-open-link-from-string`.

Something like (UNTESTED):

```
(defun org-open-link-from-string (s &optional arg reference-buffer linenum)
  "Open a link in the string S, as if it was in Org mode."
  (interactive "sLink: \nP")
  (let ((reference-buffer (or reference-buffer (current-buffer))))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (let ((org-inhibit-startup (not reference-buffer)))
    (org-mode)
    (insert s)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (goto-line linenum)  ;;;;;;;; ADD THIS LINE ;;;;;;;;;;;
    (when reference-buffer
      (setq org-link-abbrev-alist-local
        (with-current-buffer reference-buffer
          org-link-abbrev-alist-local)))
    (org-open-at-point arg reference-buffer)))))
```

and in `org-edit-special` change this line:

```
(t (user-error "No valid file specified")))))))
```

to something like this:

```
(t (user-error "No valid file specified"))))))
  nil nil ((string-match ":lines +\"\\(\\(?:[0-9]+\\)?-\\(?:[0-9]+\\)?\\)\"" value)
            (match-string 1 value))
```

I guess this could be done with simple advices, but I wouldn't know how.